# Inexplicable exception in View.onTouchEvent()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, touch-event

Few weeks ago I published my first game in Android Market. During beta tests everything was fine, but recently I've received several errors like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at towe.papersoccer.GameView.onTouchEvent(GameView.java:166)
 at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3819)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1907)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1159)
 at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1891)
 at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1811)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4632)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is a code of method that throw the exception:

```
// This class extends View

private PointF  anchor;
private PointF  holder;

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        anchor = new PointF(e.getX(), e.getY());
        holder = new PointF(anchor.x, anchor.y);
        return true;
    } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        holder.x = e.getX();
        holder.y = e.getY();
        return true;
    } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        float length = PointF.length(holder.x-anchor.x, holder.y-anchor.y);
        if (length > 20) {
            int row = 0;
            int column = 0;
            if (holder.x == anchor.x) {
                if (holder.y > anchor.y) {
                    row = 1;
                } else {
                    row = -1;
                }
            } else {
                float a = (holder.y-anchor.y)/(holder.x-anchor.x);
                if (holder.x > anchor.x) {
                    if (a > 1/2.5) row = 1;
                    else if (a < -1/2.5) row = -1;
                    if (a > -2.5 && a < 2.5) column = 1;
                } else {
                    if (a > 1/2.5) row = -1;
                    else if (a < -1/2.5) row = 1;
                    if (a > -2.5 && a < 2.5) column = -1;
                }
            }
            row += current.row;
            column += current.column;
            move(row, column, true); // As you can see in stack trace, this method doesn't throw the exception
        }
        anchor = null;
        holder = null;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have no idea why on some devices this method throws the NullPointerException. I guess that's because they sometimes may not call this method with MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, so *anchor* and *holder* are not defined... But is it even possible? I can't find any other reasons that could explain the exception.

Hope you will help me, and sorry for my language mistakes, Towe.

Answer (score 0):

`anchor` and `holder` are only assigned a value in the first if statement (the one with `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`). 
Consequently, both `anchor` and `holder` are unassigned (`== null`) in the other else if branches (`MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`) causing a NPE when trying to assign or access `holder.x`, `holder.y,`anchor.x`or`anchor.y`.

Comment: But if there is always ACTION_DOWN before ACTION_MOVE, NPE shouldn't be throwed because in ACTION_DOWN anchor and holder are assigned. Moreover these variables aren't unassigned in ACTION_MOVE, so access to them in ACTION_UP shouldn't throw NPE too.By the way, remember that the exception has been thrown only few times.

Comment: The stack trace reveals that the NPE is thrown in the `onTouchEvent()` method on line 166 in the `GameView` class. Which is the corresponding line in your code snippet?

Comment: I'm beginner so I didn't know that this number indicates to the line in source code... Anyway, line 166 contains 'holder.x = e.getX();' and line 170 (throwed few NPEs too) contains 'float length = PointF.length(holder.x-anchor.x, holder.y-anchor.y);'. It means that sometimes (or on some devices) onTouchEvent() with MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN is not executed. Now I can solve my problem, thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad that I could help. Consider to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235) the answer if it solved your problem.